# how to provide ignore regex for sublimerge?

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'd like to be able to provide a regular expression for text to ignore when creating diff's with sublimerge. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Borys, the author of sublimerge:

> Please take a look at http://www.sublimerge.com/sm3/docs/configuration.html#default-settings-diff-algorithm - there is a „intraline_unimportant_regexps” setting that should do what you want, however this is not a live setting so it requires the diff to be re-processed.

In sublimerge3 (2?) there is a "Recompare buffers" option in the "sublimerge" section of the right click context menu (when you're viewing a diff). Also F5 will re-process the diff.

Note that at present this only changes the highlight on "unimportant" differences, they still appear when you 'go to next diff'.